# Why "lines.upper()" doesn't apply the change while printing?

Tags: uppercase

I typed this code in an idle file, but while printing, `lines.upper()` hasn't been applied to the variable, why is it, and what should I do?

```
lines=input("type your text :")
lines.upper()
print(lines)
```

Comment: Is this Python? You should specify the programming language as the first tag.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: @Irreducible: Why? The only fault I can see in this question is that the programming language isn't specified.

Comment: @Antti29 - and "Include all Relevant Tags" is one section of that page.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using Python. Then you should write your code like this:

```
lines=input("type your text :")
lines = lines.upper()     # changed here
print(lines)
```

---

About str.upper(), the [document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) explains that:

> Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters converted to uppercase.

This means that str.upper() won't change the variable itself, but return a converted copy instead. We can confirm this from the [source code](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c)  of str.upper().

```
## {"upper", (PyCFunction)string_upper, METH_NOARGS, upper__doc__},

static PyObject *
string_upper(PyStringObject *self)
{
    char *s;
    Py_ssize_t i, n = PyString_GET_SIZE(self);
    PyObject *newobj;

    newobj = PyString_FromStringAndSize(NULL, n);
    if (!newobj)
        return NULL;

    s = PyString_AS_STRING(newobj);

    Py_MEMCPY(s, PyString_AS_STRING(self), n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int c = Py_CHARMASK(s[i]);
        if (islower(c))
            s[i] = _toupper(c);
    }

    return newobj;
}
```

Even if you are using other program language, you should find the answer from its official document or somewhere like that.